# How to insert 6 tikzpictures in a landscape page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, landscape, axis, tikz-pic

I inserted a landscaped page in my document to containing 6 figures. I want 4 small **figures** in the first row and 2 big **figures** in the second row. I have tried many ways but can't find a beautiful solution. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} % The class file specifying the document structure
\input{preamble.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\LARGE {Weekly Report}}\\
\end{center} 
\vspace{0.5cm}
\input{chapters/financial}
\newpage
\input{chapters/sale_by_product}
\input{chapters/customers}
\end{document}
```

Premble:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{vntex}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  top    = 2.0 cm,
  bottom = 2.0 cm,
  left   = 1.5 cm,
  right  = 1.5 cm,
  %headsep=0mm,
  %footskip=50pt,
  %includeheadfoot,
  %showframe=true %%% show frame
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,epsfig,latexsym,multicol,array,hhline}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pifont}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,colorlinks=true,frenchlinks=true} 
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{xstring}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds,automata,positioning,trees,shapes,calc,through,bending,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{assoccnt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\usetkzobj{all}

\newfontfamily{\jfsl}{JosefinSans-Light}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\jfsr}{JosefinSans-Regular}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\jfssm}{JosefinSans-SemiBold}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\osl}{OpenSans-Light}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\osr}{OpenSans-Regular}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\ossm}{OpenSans-SemiBold}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\rwl}{Raleway-Light}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\rwr}{Raleway-Regular}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\newfontfamily{\rwsm}{Raleway-SemiBold}[Extension = .ttf, Path = font/]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}p{#1}}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
%   \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Danh mục hình ảnh}
%   \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Danh mục bảng}
%   \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chương}
%   \renewcommand{\figurename}{Hình}
%   \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Tóm tắt}
%   \renewcommand{\bibname}{Tài liệu tham khảo}  
%   \renewcommand{\refname}{Tài liệu tham khảo}  
%   \renewcommand\tablename{Bảng}
  %
}
\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\numprint{#1}}
\regtotcounter{section}
\def\shotseparator{-}
\newcommand{\shotlistname}{\scenename \space \shotseparator \space \charatername}
\newcommand{\Shotlistname}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase
                           \expandafter{\shotlistname}}
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise,abbr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[L]{
}
\fancyhead[R]{
\begin{tabular}{r}
        \\
        \includesvg[height=40pt]{figures/svg/urbanrolls_logo.svg}
    \end{tabular}
}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[L]{
}
\fancyfoot[R]{
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}
\definecolor{Urbancolor}{RGB}{114, 169, 66}
\SetWatermarkText{
%Confidential
}
\SetWatermarkScale{01}
\SetWatermarkColor[RGB]{114, 170, 66}
\newlength{\drop}
% \AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\input{info}
```

Info:

```
\definecolor{hous}{HTML}{b88b4d}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{79c561}
\definecolor{farming}{HTML}{ded94c}
\definecolor{trans}{HTML}{b4b4a9}
\definecolor{services}{HTML}{ff362e}
\definecolor{other}{HTML}{dbd4d3}
\definecolor{industry}{HTML}{db79c0}
\definecolor{water}{HTML}{7982db}
\definecolor{techinfra}{HTML}{303355}
\definecolor{urbanorange}{RGB}{255, 145, 77}
\definecolor{cobaltblue}{RGB}{0, 74, 173}
\definecolor{royalblue}{RGB}{82, 113, 225}
\definecolor{peach}{RGB}{82, 113, 225}
\definecolor{brightred}{RGB}{255, 22, 22}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{255, 222, 89}


\pgfmathsetmacro{\barwidthchart}{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\minipagesize}{0.4}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\appetizersnone}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\appetizersntwo}{\appetizersnone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\appetizersw}{\appetizersntwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\appetizersr}{\appetizersntwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\bunsnone}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bunsntwo}{\bunsnone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bunsw}{\bunsntwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bunsr}{\bunsntwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\vermicellinone}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\vermicellintwo}{\vermicellinone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\vermicelliw}{\vermicellintwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\vermicellir}{\vermicellintwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\chefspecialtynone}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\chefspecialtyntwo}{\chefspecialtynone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\chefspecialtyw}{\chefspecialtyntwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\chefspecialtyr}{\chefspecialtyntwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rollsnone}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rollsntwo}{\rollsnone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rollsw}{\rollsntwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rollsr}{\rollsntwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\phonone}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phontwo}{\phonone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phow}{\phontwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phor}{\phontwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\banhminone}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\banhmintwo}{\banhminone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\banhmiw}{\banhmintwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\banhmir}{\banhmintwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\specialdrinksnone}{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\specialdrinksntwo}{\specialdrinksnone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\specialdrinksw}{\specialdrinksntwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\specialdrinksr}{\specialdrinksntwo/5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\softdrinksnone}{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\softdrinksntwo}{\softdrinksnone+0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\softdrinksw}{\softdrinksntwo/4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\softdrinksr}{\softdrinksntwo/5}
```

```
\section*{Sales by Product}
\input{figures/tex/group}
$\;$\\\\
\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\input{figures/tex/appetizers}
\switchcolumn
\input{figures/tex/rolls}
\end{paracol}




\afterpage{%
\clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
\thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
% \input{figures/tex/steamed_bun}
% \input{figures/tex/vermicelli}
% \input{figures/tex/banh_mi}
% \input{figures/tex/specialty}
% \input{figures/tex/special_drink}
% \input{figures/tex/soft_drink}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage% Flush page
}
```

Appetizers:

```
\begin{figure}[b!]
    \centering
   \resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = 4.6,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= .6\textwidth,
            height = 0.4\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4},
            extra x tick labels = {Egg Rolls, Fried Wonton, Fried Tofu, Popcorn Chicken},
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, very thick, fill=orange!60] coordinates {
                (1,28)
                (2,13)
                (3,2)
                (4,11)
            };
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%\captionsetup{margin={-3cm,0cm}}
\caption*{Appetizers}
\end{figure}
```

Spring Rolls:

```
\begin{figure}[b!]
    \centering
        \resizebox{.617\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = 6.6,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= .9\textwidth,
            height = 0.4\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
            extra x tick labels = { Pork \& Shrimp Rolls, Shrimp Rolls, Grilled Pork Rolls, Grills Chicken Rolls, Lemongrass Beef Rolls, Tofu \& Veggie Rolls},
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, very thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (1,18)
                (2,13)
                (3,8)
                (4,8)
                (5,12)
                (6,5)
            };
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%\captionsetup{margin={-3.25cm,0cm}}
\caption*{Urban Spring Rolls}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I want a landspace page next containing 6 **figures** with 4 small **figures** in the first row and 2 in the second row (with the caption for each firgure). Here is what I done so far.

[image]

Buns:

```
\begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = \bunsntwo,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= .3\textwidth,
            height = .35\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = \barwidthchart mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3},
            extra x tick labels = {Grilled Pork Buns, Grilled Chicken Buns, Lemongrass Beef Buns},
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (1,14)
                (2,12)
                (3,7)
            };
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (4,15)
                (5,17)
                (6,9)
                (7,7)
            };
        \end{axis}
```

Vermicelli:

```
\begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = \vermicellintwo,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= .4\textwidth,
            height = .35\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = \barwidthchart mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4},
            extra x tick labels = {Grilled Pork Vermicelli, Grilled Chicken Vermicelli, Lemongrass Beef Vermicelli,Tofu + Veggie Vermicelli},
            at={(0.3\textwidth,0)}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (1,15)
                (2,17)
                (3,9)
                (4,7)
            };
        \end{axis}
```

Banh mi:

```
\begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = \banhmintwo,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= .5\textwidth,
            height = 0.4\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = \barwidthchart mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            extra x tick labels = {Grilled Pork Banh Mi, Grilled Chicken Banh Mi, Crispy Pork Banh Mi,Lemongrass Beef Banh Mi, Tofu + Veggie Banh Mi},
            at={(0.8\textwidth,0)}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (1,16)
                (2,5)
                (3,0)
                (4,8)
                (5,2)
            };
        \end{axis}
```

Chef specialty:

```
\begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = \chefspecialtyntwo,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= .3\textwidth,
            height = 0.35\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = \barwidthchart mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3},
            extra x tick labels = {Wonton Soup, Egg Noodle Soup, Combination Fried Rice},
            at={(1.12\textwidth,0)}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (1,6)
                (2,1)
                (3,9)
            };
        \end{axis}
```

Special Drink:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = \specialdrinksntwo,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= \specialdrinksw\textwidth,
            height = 0.4\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            extra x tick labels = {Passion Fruit Refresher, Artichoke Iced Tea, Iced Milk Tea , Iced Thai Tea, Taro Milk Tea, Matcha Green Tea, Viet Style Black Coffee, Viet Style Milk Coffee}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=cobaltblue] coordinates {
                (1,7)
                (2,1)
                (3,4)
                (4,12)
                (5,5)
                (6,2)
                (7,0)
                (8,1)
            };
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Soft Drink:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = \softdrinksntwo,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= \softdrinksw\textwidth,
            height = 0.4\textwidth,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra x ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            extra x tick labels = {Coke, Diet Coke, Fanta, Dr.Pepper, Root Beer, Lemonade, Ice Tea}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=royalblue] coordinates {
                (1,2)
                (2,1)
                (3,0)
                (4,2)
                (5,1)
                (6,4)
                (7,3)
            };
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend the first code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your code employs of a lot of packages, and it's not immediately obvious which packages are required. In order to eliminate pointless and time-consuming guesswork related to the choice of packages, you would do yourself a big favor by listing the LaTeX packages you employ and the document class that's in use.

Comment: I just added them. Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: I am finding a way to make the code auto adjust sizes and positions base on the number of columns and values in each figure. If there is any clue it will be nice.

Comment: Should the captions be individual captions (figure 1, figure 2, ...)  or subcaptions (figure 1a, figure 1b...)?

Comment: Why not use a portrait page with 3 rows of 2 tikzpictures each?

Comment: Since you already set the widths of the individual tikzpictures: 0.3+0.4+0.5+0.3 adds up to 1.5\textwidth. How should these 4 tikzpictures fit into one line?

Comment: Since all the x tick labels are quite long, probably using a horizontal bar chart instead of a vertical one could be helpful?

Comment: @leandriis 1/The captions should be individual.
2/Because the two last figures are too long.
3/I am trying many ways. Any possible solution will be ok.
4/I will try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up add appetizers and rolls in the same page and created an auto-adjust solution.

```
\documentclass{article} % The class file specifying the document structure
\input{preamble.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\LARGE {Weekly Report}}\\
\end{center} 
\vspace{0.5cm}
\input{chapters/financial}
\newpage
\input{chapters/sale_by_product}
\input{chapters/customers}
\end{document}
```

Preamble:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{vntex}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  top    = 2.0 cm,
  bottom = 2.0 cm,
  left   = 1.5 cm,
  right  = 1.5 cm,
  %headsep=0mm,
  %footskip=50pt,
  %includeheadfoot,
  %showframe=true %%% show frame
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,epsfig,latexsym,multicol,array,hhline}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pifont}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,colorlinks=true,frenchlinks=true} 
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{xstring}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,backgrounds,automata,positioning,trees,shapes,calc,through,bending,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{assoccnt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}p{#1}}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
%   \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Danh mục hình ảnh}
%   \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Danh mục bảng}
%   \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chương}
%   \renewcommand{\figurename}{Hình}
%   \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Tóm tắt}
%   \renewcommand{\bibname}{Tài liệu tham khảo}  
%   \renewcommand{\refname}{Tài liệu tham khảo}  
%   \renewcommand\tablename{Bảng}
  %
}
\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\numprint{#1}}
\regtotcounter{section}
\def\shotseparator{-}
\newcommand{\shotlistname}{\scenename \space \shotseparator \space \charatername}
\newcommand{\Shotlistname}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase
                           \expandafter{\shotlistname}}
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise,abbr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[L]{
}
\fancyhead[R]{
\begin{tabular}{r}
        \\
        \includesvg[height=40pt]{figures/svg/urbanrolls_logo.svg}
    \end{tabular}
}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[L]{
}
\fancyfoot[R]{
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}
\definecolor{Urbancolor}{RGB}{114, 169, 66}
\SetWatermarkText{
%Confidential
}
\SetWatermarkScale{01}
\SetWatermarkColor[RGB]{114, 170, 66}
\newlength{\drop}
% \AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
%\input{info}
\input{tikz_info/glob}
\input{tikz_info/aptz}
\input{tikz_info/buns}
\input{tikz_info/vmcl}
\input{tikz_info/ubst}
\input{tikz_info/pho}
\input{tikz_info/bnmi}
\input{tikz_info/roll}
\input{tikz_info/spcd}
\input{tikz_info/stdk}
```

Sale Section:

```
\section*{Sales by Product}
\input{figures/tex/group}
$\;$\\\\
\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\input{figures/tex/appetizers}
\switchcolumn
\input{figures/tex/rolls}
\end{paracol}

\afterpage{%
\newgeometry{
  top    = 0.0 cm,
  bottom = 0.0 cm,
  left   = 0.0 cm,
  right  = 0.0 cm,
  }
\clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[b!]
    \begin{center}
\input{figures/tex/appetizers_2}
\input{figures/tex/steamed_bun}
\input{figures/tex/vermicelli}
\input{figures/tex/specialty}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
\input{figures/tex/pho}
\input{figures/tex/banh_mi}
\input{figures/tex/rolls_2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \begin{center}
\input{figures/tex/special_drink}
\input{figures/tex/soft_drink}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
% \input{figures/tex/steamed_bun}
% \input{figures/tex/vermicelli}
% \input{figures/tex/banh_mi}
% \input{figures/tex/specialty}
% \input{figures/tex/special_drink}
% \input{figures/tex/soft_drink}
\end{landscape}

\clearpage% Flush page
}
\restoregeometry
```

Glob:

```
\definecolor{hous}{HTML}{b88b4d}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{79c561}
\definecolor{farming}{HTML}{ded94c}
\definecolor{trans}{HTML}{b4b4a9}
\definecolor{services}{HTML}{ff362e}
\definecolor{other}{HTML}{dbd4d3}
\definecolor{industry}{HTML}{db79c0}
\definecolor{water}{HTML}{7982db}
\definecolor{techinfra}{HTML}{303355}
\definecolor{urbanorange}{RGB}{255, 145, 77}
\definecolor{cobaltblue}{RGB}{0, 74, 173}
\definecolor{royalblue}{RGB}{82, 113, 225}
\definecolor{peach}{RGB}{82, 113, 225}
\definecolor{brightred}{RGB}{255, 22, 22}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{255, 222, 89}


\pgfmathsetmacro{\tikzbarwidth}{1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tikzscale}{0.55}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tikzchartheight}{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tikzlabelwidth}{3.5}

\newcommand{\calntwo}[1]{#1+0.5}
\newcommand{\calminipagesizefour}[1]{#1+2.4}
\newcommand{\calminipagesizethree}[1]{#1+4.275}
\newcommand{\calminipagesizetwo}[1]{#1+4.85}
\newcommand{\calnamelength}[1]{#1/8}
\newcommand{\calchartwidth}[1]{#1*2.5}
\newcommand{\calchartheight}[3]{#1}
```

Aptz setting:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aptznone}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aptznoc}{15}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\aptzntwo}{\calntwo{\aptznone}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aptzminipagesize}{\calminipagesizefour{\aptzntwo}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aptznamelength}{\calnamelength{\aptznoc}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aptzchartwidth}{\calchartwidth{\aptzntwo}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aptzchartheight}{\calchartheight{\tikzchartheight}{\aptznamelength}{\aptznone}}
```

Here **\aptznone** is the number of columns.
Same format for the rest.

Appetizers:

```
\begin{minipage}{\aptzminipagesize cm}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tikzscale]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xmin = 0.5,
            xmax = \aptzntwo,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Volume,
            width= \aptzchartwidth cm,
            height = \aptzchartheight cm,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            bar width = \tikzbarwidth cm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            xtick = \empty,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east, align=right, text width=\tikzlabelwidth cm},
            extra x ticks = {1,..., \aptznone},
            extra x tick labels = {Egg Rolls, Fried Wonton, Fried Tofu, Popcorn Chicken},
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, very thick, fill=orange!60] coordinates {
                (1,28)
                (2,13)
                (3,2)
                (4,11)
            };
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Appetizers}
\end{minipage}
```

same for the rest.

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion using horizontal bar charts on a portrait page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  top    = 2.0 cm,
  bottom = 2.0 cm,
  left   = 1.5 cm,
  right  = 1.5 cm,
  ]{geometry}


\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{Urbancolor}{RGB}{114, 169, 66}
\definecolor{cobaltblue}{RGB}{0, 74, 173}
\definecolor{royalblue}{RGB}{82, 113, 225}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\bunsnone}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bunsntwo}{\bunsnone+0.5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\vermicellinone}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\vermicellintwo}{\vermicellinone+0.5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\chefspecialtynone}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\chefspecialtyntwo}{\chefspecialtynone+0.5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rollsnone}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rollsntwo}{\rollsnone+0.5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\banhminone}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\banhmintwo}{\banhminone+0.5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\specialdrinksnone}{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\specialdrinksntwo}{\specialdrinksnone+0.5}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\softdrinksnone}{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\softdrinksntwo}{\softdrinksnone+0.5}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
           xbar,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = \bunsntwo,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            xlabel= Volume,
            width= 0.7\textwidth,
%            height = 0.4\textwidth,
%            %ymajorgrids = true,
%            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            ytick = \empty,
            yticklabels = \empty,
%            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra y ticks = {1, 2, 3},
            extra y tick labels = {Grilled Pork , Grilled Chicken , Lemongrass Beef },
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (14,1)
                (12,2)
                (7,3)
            };
        \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Buns}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
           xbar,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = \vermicellintwo,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            xlabel= Volume,
            width= 0.7\textwidth,
%            height = 0.4\textwidth,
%            %ymajorgrids = true,
%            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            ytick = \empty,
            yticklabels = \empty,
%            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra y ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4},
            extra y tick labels = {Grilled Pork, Grilled Chicken, Lemongrass Beef,Tofu + Veggie },
            at={(0.3\textwidth,0)}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (15,1)
                (17,2)
                (9,3)
                (7,4)
            };
        \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Vermicelli}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = \banhmintwo,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            xlabel= Volume,
            width= 0.7\textwidth,
%            height = 0.4\textwidth,
%            %ymajorgrids = true,
%            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            ytick = \empty,
            yticklabels = \empty,
%            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra y ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            extra y tick labels = {Grilled Pork , Grilled Chicken , Crispy Pork ,Lemongrass Beef , Tofu + Veggie },
            at={(0.8\textwidth,0)}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (16,1)
                (5,2)
                (0,3)
                (8,4)
                (2,5)
            };
        \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Banh Mi}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = \chefspecialtyntwo,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            xlabel= Volume,
            width= 0.7\textwidth,
%            height = 0.4\textwidth,
%            %ymajorgrids = true,
%            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            ytick = \empty,
            yticklabels = \empty,
%            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra y ticks = {1, 2, 3},
            extra y tick labels = {Wonton Soup, Egg Noodle Soup, Combination Fried Rice},
            at={(1.12\textwidth,0)}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=Urbancolor] coordinates {
                (6,1)
                (1,2)
                (9,3)
            };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Chef Specialty}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
            \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = \specialdrinksntwo,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            xlabel= Volume,
            width= 0.7\textwidth,
%            height = 0.4\textwidth,
%            %ymajorgrids = true,
%            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            ytick = \empty,
            yticklabels = \empty,
%            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra y ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            extra y tick labels = {Passion Fruit Refresher, Artichoke Iced Tea, Iced Milk Tea , Iced Thai Tea, Taro Milk Tea, Matcha Green Tea, Viet Style Black Coffee, Viet Style Milk Coffee}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=cobaltblue] coordinates {
                (7,1)
                (1,2)
                (4,3)
                (12,4)
                (5,5)
                (2,6)
                (0,7)
                (1,8)
            };
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Special Drinks}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = \softdrinksntwo,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 30,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            xlabel= Volume,
            width= 0.7\textwidth,
%            height = 0.4\textwidth,
%            %ymajorgrids = true,
%            bar width = 15mm,
            nodes near coords={
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            ytick = \empty,
            yticklabels = \empty,
%            x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
            extra y ticks = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            extra y tick labels = {Coke, Diet Coke, Fanta, Dr.Pepper, Root Beer, Lemonade, Ice Tea}
            ]
            \addplot[mark=none, thick, fill=royalblue] coordinates {
                (2,1)
                (1,2)
                (0,3)
                (2,4)
                (1,5)
                (4,6)
                (3,7)
            };
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Soft Drinks}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestion.